# How to print list of filenames that DONT match a regex ? Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, regex

For some reason, my code will print ALL files when I want it to only print out the files that DONT match my regex pattern.. I need it to print out the files that dont match the pattern because I dont know all the possible inconsistencies there are in the file naming. MY regex represents the correct possibilities a file name can be labeled.  I checked my regex pattern on regex101 and it is correct. I am not a coder, but I am a psychology student working on a mass database.

Ive tried making Pattern into a list pattern, and I tried putting patternList.matcher(file.getName()) into like its own Matcher variable.

```
    private static void checkFolder(File root, Pattern patternList) {
        for(File file : root.listFiles())

        if(file.isFile()){

            if(patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
                checkFolder(rootFolder, patternList);
            else 
                System.out.println(file); //print if it does not match
        }
```

For example, If my code looks at these file names:

- 95F Front Anger.BW
- 95F.Front.Anger.C.Micro
- 95F.Front.Fear.C.Micro
- 95F.Front.Frown.BW

And my regex is this:

```
    Pattern patternList = Pattern.compile("((\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)"
    +"\\.(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C)))|"
    +"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)\\.(Neutral|Smile)\\."
    +"(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C))|"
    +"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\\.(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW))");
```

My code should only print out 95F Front Anger.BW, because it has whitespaces instead of dots, but my code still prints out all four filenames.

I also tried doing this:

```
    private static void checkFolder(File root, Pattern patternList) {
    for(File file : root.listFiles())

        if(file.isFile()){

            if(!patternList.matcher(file.getName()).matches())
            {
               System.out.println(file); //print the file that doesnt match the regex
            }
            else
            {
            checkFolder(rootFolder, patternList);
            }    



        }
 }
```

Comment: Oh, you're missing the Boolean, just add `.matches()` at the end. Oh, you have that ..

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhh, im not sure if its the for loop or the if statement that is the issue

Comment: You could try to break it up `Matcher m = patternList.matcher();` then `if ( m.matches() )` but ..

Comment: What is `rootFolder`? Did you perhaps intend to try a recursive call using `file`? If so, you should only try that if `file.isDirectory()`.

Comment: yeah i already tried to break it up :/

Comment: rootFolder is my file path

Comment: Why are you using regex? What's wrong with a simple `if(){}` which checks the filename against a blacklist?

Comment: I haven’t learned what a blacklist is. I see it’s like hash?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
Pattern patternList = Pattern.compile("((\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)"
+"\\.(Anger|Fear|Frown|Smile)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C)))|"
+"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Front|Profile|Right)\\.(Neutral|Smile)\\."
+"(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW|HighLight|LowLight|MedLight)\\.(BW\\.Micro|BW|C\\.Micro|C))|"
+"(\\d{1,3}(F|M)\\.(Selfie1|Selfie2|StudentID)\\.(C\\.Micro|C|BW\\.Micro|BW))");

String[] tests = { "95F Front Anger.BW",
                   "95F.Front.Anger.C.Micro",
                   "95F.Front.Fear.C.Micro",
                   "95F.Front.Frown.BW" };

for (String s : tests)
    System.out.printf("%-7s %s%n", patternList.matcher(s).matches(), s);
```

*Output*

```
false   95F Front Anger.BW
true    95F.Front.Anger.C.Micro
true    95F.Front.Fear.C.Micro
true    95F.Front.Frown.BW
```

It matches the way you want it to.

Perhaps `file.getName()` doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: What’s the best way to add the filesnames into a string list so I could do something like what you’re doing?

Comment: Like string<list> or string []?

Comment: Are these the same thing, no?

Comment: @MaliaMyers No, `String[]` is an array of strings, `List<String>` is a list of strings. Arrays are fixed-size, so generally not what you want. Too add a string to a `List<String>`, call .... *<wait for it>* .... the `add(...)` method.

Comment: thank you! i was able to successfully add my filenames into a list<file>... i think im going to try to use toString() to then compare them with my regex if file.getName() is my possible issue